# How can I test LDAP connection using JNDI

Tags: ldap, jndi

I get an exception `javax.naming.NameNotFountException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name = 'DC=my-company, DC=group'`

The cause of it could be, that the DN `'DC=my-company, DC=group'` is invalid. But such exception occurs also then if I set `ldapAdServer`, `ldapUsername`, `ldapPassword` to unvalid values. So, I suppose my LDAP connection was not properly set.

How can I test LDAP connection whether it was created successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`No Such Object` is an error returned by a directory server when the object of the request does not exist. Use the correct base object instead of `dc=my-company,dc=com`.

If you do not know the base object, you may be able to discover the directory prefix (or naming context) by querying the [root DSE](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/the-root-dse-is-that-entry-with-zero-rdns-and-contains-information-about-the-directory-server/). If you do not know the correct base object, you can use the prefix or naming context as the base object until you discover the base object (which should be closer to your data than the prefix or naming context).

More generally speaking, **JNDI** should not be used if you know for certain that your directory server will be accessed via LDAP. You will be able to quickly develop working, practical code that is more easily understood by others and more efficient if you use a professional quality LDAP SDK such as the one from [UnboundID](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/). The standard edition is free of cost and comes with the source code.

Answer (score 0):

> But such exception occurs also then if I set ldapAdServer,
>   ldapUsername, ldapPassword to unvalid values.

No it doesn't. You get a different exception.

Comment: well, I would get a different exception, if I would be properly connected to LDAP, isn't it?

Comment: @mtm This comment makes no sense to me. If you are properly connected, you can get the NameNotFoundException you mentioned in your question. If you aren't properly connected enough to do a search, you can't possibly get that exception. For example, if the credentials are wrong, you get an AuthenticationException.

Comment: I changed ldapAdServer to "0.0.0.777", the ldapUsername to "yxcv". There are neither such server, no such user. So, I just cannot be properly connected. After all, I got the same NameNotFoundException. That's why I thought, that it doesn't depend whether I connected. I'm really suprising that the NameNotFoundException occurs if I am properly connected. Thanks for reply @ejp!

Comment: @mtm How are you using these variables?